# VBA - Can't use Sheets object without error

Tags: excel, vba

I have an Excel file with one sheet called `Master`.

I have a button to delete a value from the database. This is what I have written that's relevant:

```
Sub delete_this()
    On Error GoTo ErrorCatch
    simple = Sheets("Master")
    .........
ErrorCatch
    MsgBox(Err.Description)
End Sub
```

It fails immediately when I use `Sheets`, saying "Application-defined or object-defined error." However I'm using other code that I know works as a reference and they called this no problem (though their file had multiple sheets).

Also in general I'm new to VBA and find it pretty unintuitive with its error messages, and finding out variable values. So any advice there would also be appreciated.

Comment: `Dim simple as Worksheet` - `Set simple = worksheets("Master")`  you forgot the `Set`

Comment: Note: [`Sheets`is an object](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/office/vba/api/Excel.Sheets), not a function.

Comment: @GeroldBroser note: *in this context*, `Sheets` is a **property** of the `Global` hidden module, which returns an object of type `Sheets` off `ActiveWorkbook`. So depending on how you look at it, "Sheets" is either a *class* or a *property*, but not an *object*.

Comment: @MathieuGuindon Now I remember why I abandoned VB(A) from my CV a long time ago: a _property_ that's not a container for some _value_ but returns something and which is a _class_ or a _property_ though the doc from the OEM says it's an _object_. Thanks a lot for reminding me! ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentioned in a comment by Scott Craner, you need to use the `Set` statement whenever assigning an *object* to a variable when using VBA. This little gotcha doesn't exist in VB.NET, and is easy to forget about these days.

```
Set simple = Sheets("Master")
```

Comment: How do I tell which functions simple can call now? For example, I thought simple.Range("value").Value should've worked.

Comment: have you declared simple with a data type (e.g. Dim simple As WorkSheet)? If you do this, "intellisense" should tell you what methods and properties are available for use on simple when you type the dot after typing simple

Comment: @JesusMonroe `Sheets` is a collection of many things, *including* `Worksheet` objects. It can also include `Chart` and a half-dozen legacy sheet types. Use the `Worksheets` collection if you want to be 100% sure you're pulling a `Worksheet` object.